# Create one invoice from many purchase orders

Tags: odoo, invoice, purchase-order

In Openerp v7, I have sent two (or more) purchase orders to the same supplier and he sent me one invoice for those orders.
Is there a way or a module to create one invoice grouping the two orders.

Note 1: I don't want to merge the orders, but just one unique invoice (as I received) related to both.
Note 2 : the orders concern service type product so, there are no pickings to be invoiced.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

one solution is to set the invoice_method to "Based on Purchase Order lines" for this type or orders.

Then, when we receive the supplier invoice, we can select the concerned purchase order lines  and create an invoice in accordance to the one received.

Not exactly group nor merge but it can do the trick